# how to define a compound and hashed mongodb index?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I know that a compound index is defined like this:

```
db.products.ensureIndex( { "item": 1, "stock": 1 } )
```

and a hashed a simple index like this:

```
db.active.ensureIndex( { item: "hashed" } )
```

question is how to achieve both?

Comment: Apparently, 7 yrs down the line, you can now [do this with compatibility version 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65844259/1746118).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [hashed index documentaion](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-hashed-index/) You can't!

> MongoDB supports hashed indexes of any single field. The hashing
> function collapses sub-documents and computes the hash for the entire
> value, but does not support multi-key (i.e. arrays) indexes.
>
> You may **not** create compound indexes that have hashed index fields

PS: The above is valid for versions 2.4 and 2.6 (which is the latest at the moment)

PS2: According to @naman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65844259/687142) it is now possible in version 4.4

Comment: Multikey index is not the same as Compound index. In the example, item and stock are not arrays.

Comment: I know, I didn't say the oposite. At the end it says that **you may not create compound indexes that have hashed index fields**, and that you can only create a compound index of a single field, which answers what you are asking.
 If you absolutely need the hashed index of those two fields, make them a single field as a subdocument, which, according to the doc, works.

Comment: Well, my intention is to do what you say at the end, compose the two fields and then calculate the hash, not to hash a single field and then compose it (as it is clearly not allowed as documentation says). I just supposed there was a way to hash the automatically composed field. But as you say, I will need to create a new field and hash it.

Comment: You can vote on this feature being included in future versions at: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10220

Comment: Apparently, 7 yrs down the line, you can now [do this with compatibility version 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65844259/1746118).

Comment: Nice! It was about time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve a compound hashed index, it's feasible with version 4.4 and above. From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-hashed/#create-a-compound-hashed-index), you can now create it as:

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } )
db.collection.createIndex( { "fieldA" : 1, "fieldB" : "hashed", "fieldC" : -1 } )
```

for the particular example in question

```
db.products.ensureIndex( { "item": "hashed", "stock": 1 } )
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 4.4 support compound index with single hashed which can be created like

`db.collection.createIndex( { "colA" : 1, "fieldB" : "hashed" } )`

Note: Make sure **featureCompatibilityVersion** set to 4.4 so that you can create compound hashed index.

`db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } )`

Comment: thanks for the contribution, the bounty here is to [draw attention to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65844259/1746118), the answer you made would end up being a duplicate. hence, would suggest closing it in favor of the other answer.